# Time formats match but still getting error. ValueError: time data 'Time' does match format specified pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time, python-datetime

my data column looks like this:

```
0 Time

1 2014-07-28 00:17:35

2 2014-07-28 00:18:05

3 2014-07-28 01:50:54

4 2014-07-28 01:51:24

5 2014-07-28 01:53:57

6 2014-07-28 01:54:56
```

my code looks like this:

```
df['Epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and my error looks like this:

> ValueError: time data 'Time' does match format specified

really not sure if I'm missing something here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe is wrongly loaded: your header is interpreted as a row and is the first row of your dataframe. `pd.to_datetime` tries to transform the string 'Time' found row 0.

Load correctly your dataframe by getting the row 0 loaded as a header instead.

Something like this can move the firs row as colum titles and delete it as a row:

```
df.columns = df.ix[0]
df = df.drop(0)
```